# How to return jsx for multiple arrays iterated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following arrays iterated and I'm able to console.log the result I want.

```
import React from 'react';

const MyApplications = ({ currentUser, jobs, jobApplications }) => {
   
 const jobAppsFromCurrentUser = jobApplications.filter(jobApp => jobApp.musician_id === currentUser.id)

  return (
    <div>
        <div>
          {
             jobs.filter(job => {
              jobAppsFromCurrentUser.map(jobApp => {
                if (jobApp.job_id === job.id) {
                  console.log(job)
                }
              })
            })
          }
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyApplications
```

Result:

[image]

But ultimately, I need to render each `job` as jsx. I want to be able to do something like this (this doesn't return anything):

```
      <div>
          {
             jobs.filter(job => {
              jobAppsFromCurrentUser.map(jobApp => {
                if (jobApp.job_id === job.id) {
                  return (
                    <div>
                       <h1>{job.title}</h1>
                    </div>
                  )
                }
              })
            })
          }
      </div>
```

**Solution:**

```
import React from 'react';

const MyApplications = ({ currentUser, jobs, jobApplications }) => {
 
  const jobAppsFromCurrentUser = jobApplications.filter(jobApp => jobApp.musician_id === currentUser.id)

  const includesID = (id) => {
    const onFilter = jobAppsFromCurrentUser.filter((jobApp) => jobApp.job_id == id);

    return onFilter.length > 0 ? true : false;
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <div>
             {jobs.map((job) => {
              if (includesID(job.id)) {
                return (
                  <div key={job.id}>
                    <h1>{job.title}</h1>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyApplications
```

Comment: You need to `map` the filtered array. `filter` expects a boolean return so your inner `map` is just discarded and the returned jsx is just read as a truthy value to include the element in the result of the filter.

Comment: Why are you using `filter`?  If the goal is to "render each job" then `map` over the `jobs` array and return a JSX element for each one.

Comment: Thanks! I'll work on it and update you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the ID's match.

```
const includesID = (id) => {
    const onFilter = jobs.filter((item) => item.id == id);

    return onFilter.length > 0 ? true : false;
  };
```

And render it as

```
<div>
      {jobAppsFromCurrentUser.map((jobApp) => {
        if (includesID(jobApp.id)) {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>{job.title}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
```

Comment: this isn't correct this seems to work because of JS nonsense you are not filtering anything here. it should be `jobAppsFromCurrentUser.fiter(j=>includesID(j.id)).map(...`

Comment: also key should be equal to ID.

Comment: But i'm checking if there is a job with the same ID of the job being rendered by filtering it

Comment: Not what I was getting at. map always returns a value if none is specified it returns undefined that's why your array will have nulls where items where filtered. The key is needed for tracking items by react.